# How to save image image with current location and some infos in FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to save image taken in app with some information as current location(latitude, longtitude),around places(restaurant or something nearest place) ,some variables .this photo wil be shown in application in other page.At the moment i am saving image with rename file and get all infos from file name.Have any other method to save infos with image

AT the moment I am saving image as
/data/user/0/com.example.tflite_image_classification/cache/latidude@longtitude@aroundPlace.jpg

Can anyone have other stategy for save share please

Comment: What database you're using?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the google map package, there is a method exists in the instance which is called takeSnapShot.

ex: mapController.takeSnapShot();

Comment: I am not using google map I am take a picture from camera and need to save with current place  ,around restaurant and some infos

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).